# NLP Python Finding top 5 themes in a verbatim - survey

Tags: python, nlp

I would like to reach out to you with a question that I hope you have some inputs.
In terms of verbatims analysis, for NLP, if I would like to derive the top 5 themes out of the verbatim (not topics, but meaningful themes), may I know if you have any suggestions for NLP packages/tool that I should read into?

I have 1TB of verbatim and I try to find the top 5 themes that people are most discussed about.

Thank you!

Comment: You can use NLTK Library for this.

Comment: can you give an example of what you want to obtain